# How to create directory in android framework?

Tags: android, frameworks, directory, mkdirs

I want to create my directory in android framework.
For example, "/stoage/myTestDir/"

So, i try to add this code in "Kitkat/frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/BootReceiver.java".

BootReceiver.java

```
@Overrinde
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent){
    /*...*/

    if(intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")){

    File testDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/myTestDir");

    if(!testDir.exists(){
        if(testDir.mkdirs()==true){
            Log.i("mkdirs() success", "mkdirs() success");
        else{
            Log.i("mkdirs() fail", "mkdirs() fail");
        }
    }

    /*...*/
}
```

After framework building, log shows "mkdirs() fail".

So why cannot fail to create dir in android framework with my code?

thanks.

Comment: Log's argument tag should not be that way."Log.i("BootReceiver","XXX")".

Comment: Oh, i got it. Thanks for comments :)

Answer (score 0):

add permissions WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in your manifest file (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

example: http://screencast.com/t/iwdt3wFk4bV

Comment: I already added permissions in "Kitkat/frameworks/base/core/res/AndroidMenifest.xml".
But, results are same. :(

Comment: may be name of file and name of dir must be different

Comment: try new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/myTestDir/")

Comment: i try File testDir =  new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/myTestDir/"); 
But, mkdirs() failed too.